# Root of nested geometric series

Tags: roots, generating-functions, geometric-series

How, to solve:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-x^k} x^k = 0 \quad x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}
$$

Is it even possible?

There is a root at $x = 0$, but the graph shows that there should be also a root at around $x = -0.5454$.

**Edit 1 (wrong):** As comments said, my approach to solve was wrong:

Lets define $a := \frac{1}{1-x^k}$ then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a x^k = -a + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a x^k = -a + \frac{a}{1-x} = \frac{(x-1)a + a}{1-x} = \frac{ax}{1-x} = 0
\end{align}
$$

Because $a$ is an inverse, there should be only $x = 0$ a root. But this is not true.

Comment: are you treating $a$ like a constant? You shouldn't..

Comment: Sorry, but your approach is definitely wrong. The sum you are trying to calculate is related to the Digamma function.

Comment: I threated it like an unknown number. I thought, maybe it is irrelevant for root finding. Because I am realy stuck at this problem, I am "fishing" for every hope.

Comment: $a$ depends on $k$ in your definition. So you cant take it out of the sum

Answer (score 1):

You have $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{1-x^k}=\frac{\Psi_x(1)+\ln(1-x)}{\ln(x)}$, where $\Psi_x$ is the x-digamma function:

$\Psi_x(z):=\frac{1}{\Gamma_x(z)}\frac{\partial\Gamma_x(z)}{\partial z}$,

where $\Gamma_x$ is the x-gamma function (often called q-gamma function).

Valid for $-1<x<1$.

Comment: If my understanding of your notation convention is right, then $\Psi_x(1) = -\gamma$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I omited the x in front of digamma. I corrected and added its definition.